# Telegram bot process messages incorrectly

Tags: python, bots, aiogram

I have a problem with a telegram bot. It should save picture user sends to him in different folders according to button selected. But as one of buttons was pressed, no matter if pressed other it saves pictures in the folder associated with first button.

What is wrong?

```py
import logging
import os
import random

from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, types
from aiogram.contrib.fsm_storage.memory import MemoryStorage
from aiogram.types import ReplyKeyboardMarkup, KeyboardButton, ContentType
from aiogram.utils import executor

# установка уровня логирования
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

# инициализация бота и диспетчера
bot = Bot(token='xxxxxx')
dp = Dispatcher(bot, storage=MemoryStorage())


# ***********************
def random_image(path):
    folder = path
    files = os.listdir(folder)
    paths = [os.path.join(folder, file) for file in files]
    random_path = random.choice(paths)
    image = open(random_path, 'rb')
    return image


# **********************************
@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def start_command(message: types.Message):
    show_mem = KeyboardButton('show_mem')
    show_motivator = KeyboardButton('show_motivator')
    show_art = KeyboardButton('show_art')
    send_mem = KeyboardButton('send_mem')
    send_motivator = KeyboardButton('send_motivator')
    keyboard = ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True, one_time_keyboard=True).add(show_mem,
                                                                                     show_motivator,
                                                                                     show_art,
                                                                                     send_mem,
                                                                                     send_motivator)
    await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Hey!', reply_markup=keyboard)


# **********************************
@dp.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
async def button_processing(message):
    if message.text == 'show_mem':
        await bot.send_photo(message.from_user.id, photo=random_image("photo/mem"))
    if message.text == 'show_motivator':
        await bot.send_photo(message.from_user.id, photo=random_image("photo/motivator"))
    if message.text == 'show_art':
        await bot.send_photo(message.from_user.id, photo=random_image("photo/photo"))
    if message.text == 'send_mem':
        picture_saver("photo/mem")
    if message.text == 'send_motivator':
        picture_saver("photo/motivator")


# ********************************
def picture_saver(path):
    @dp.message_handler(content_types=ContentType.PHOTO)
    async def save_photo(message: types.Message):
        photo = message.photo[-1]
        file = await photo.get_file()
        filename = os.path.join(path, f"{message.text}_{message.message_id}.jpg")
        await bot.download_file(file.file_path, filename)
        await message.answer("Фото сохранено!")


# **************
if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

There are two buttons send_mem and send_motivator. If first was pressed send_mem it saves a picture in a /mem folder but when i press send_motivator it still saves picture in a /mem folder instead of /motivator. But it should save pics in a associated folders

Comment: Never share your real telegram bot token.

Comment: yeap, my mistake. Allready revoked

Answer (score 0):

Try making path a global variable.

```
path = ''

def picture_saver():
    @dp.message_handler(content_types=ContentType.PHOTO)
    async def save_photo(message: types.Message):
        photo = message.photo[-1]
        file = await photo.get_file()
        filename = os.path.join(path, f"{message.text}_{message.message_id}.jpg")
        await bot.download_file(file.file_path, filename)
        await message.answer("Фото сохранено!")


@dp.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
async def button_processing(message):
    global path
    ...
    if message.text == 'send_mem':
        path = 'photo/mem'
        picture_saver()
    if message.text == 'send_motivator':
        path = 'photo/motivator'
        picture_saver()
```

Comment: Why does that help?

Comment: The problem is in the functions picture_saver and send_photo as well when the argument path is passed to the picture_saver function. Making a global variable avoids that.